# Best way to implement Alpha Pruning in my code?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, minimax, heuristics, alpha-beta-pruning

I am currently learning Mini Max and AlphaBetaPruning with a tic tac toe game. I was able to implement and understand Mini max, but unsure how to combine alpha-beta pruning with my current code. Will I have to restart completely? or code another project?

In addition, I am familiar that Alpha-beta is just an improvisation of mini max's decisions based on using a tree to search for the best possible outcome. I

```
#Referenced: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC1QsLOXp-I
from AlphaBest import *
# board - if player inputs the numbers, it will pos his move on the board there
board = {1: ' ', 2: ' ', 3: ' ',
         4: ' ', 5: ' ', 6: ' ',
         7: ' ', 8: ' ', 9: ' '}


def printBoard(board):
    print(board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + '| ' + board[3])
    print("--+--+--")
    print(board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + '| ' + board[6])
    print("--+--+--")
    print(board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + '| ' + board[9])
    print("--+--+--")
    print("\n")


def spaceIsFree(position):
    # if board space is ' '  then it is empty
    if board[position] == ' ':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def positionsAvaliable(board):
    for key in board.keys():
        if (board[key] == ' '):
            return key
    return False

# here we insert a letter at a give position
def insertLetter(letter, position):
    # if the space is free, then we insert the letter at position
    if spaceIsFree(position):
        board[position] = letter
        printBoard(board)

        # determine if there is a draw in the game
        if checkDraw():
            print("It's a draw!")
            exit()

        # determine if there is a winner
        if checkForWin():
            if letter == 'X':
                print("Bot wins.")
                exit()
            else:
                print("player wins")
                exit()
        return

    else:
        print("Can't insert letter there")
        position = int(input("Enter a new position: "))
        insertLetter(letter, position)
        return


def checkForWin():
    # check for all possibilities to determine if the player/bot won
    if (board[1] == board[2] and board[1] == board[3] and board[1] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[4] == board[5] and board[4] == board[6] and board[4] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[7] == board[8] and board[7] == board[9] and board[7] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[1] == board[4] and board[1] == board[7] and board[1] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[2] == board[5] and board[2] == board[8] and board[2] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[3] == board[6] and board[3] == board[9] and board[3] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[1] == board[5] and board[1] == board[9] and board[1] != ' '):
        return True
    elif (board[7] == board[5] and board[7] == board[3] and board[7] != ' '):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# this is what the minimax algorithm uses for it's depth and to check which possibilities it can make
def checkWhichMarkWon(mark):
    if board[1] == board[2] and board[1] == board[3] and board[1] == mark:
        return True
    elif (board[4] == board[5] and board[4] == board[6] and board[4] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[7] == board[8] and board[7] == board[9] and board[7] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[1] == board[4] and board[1] == board[7] and board[1] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[2] == board[5] and board[2] == board[8] and board[2] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[3] == board[6] and board[3] == board[9] and board[3] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[1] == board[5] and board[1] == board[9] and board[1] == mark):
        return True
    elif (board[7] == board[5] and board[7] == board[3] and board[7] == mark):
        return True
    else:
        return False


# this determines if there is a draw by iterating through the keys
# if there are no keys in the board and no winner, then it is a draw
def checkDraw():
    for key in board.keys():
        if (board[key] == ' '):
            return False
    return True


player = '0'
bot = 'X'


def playerMove():
    position = int(input("Enter the position for O: "))
    insertLetter(player, position)
    return


def botMove():
    bestScore = -1000
    bestMove = 0
    for key in board.keys():
        if (board[key] == ' '):
            board[key] = bot
            score = miniMax(board, 0, False)
            board[key] = ' '
            if (score > bestScore):
                bestScore = score
                bestMove = key

    insertLetter(bot, bestMove)
    return

def miniMax(board, depth, isMaximizing):
    # need to find terminal states here
    if checkWhichMarkWon(bot):
        return 100
    elif checkWhichMarkWon(player):
        return -100
    elif checkDraw():
        return 0

    # here the bot plays against itself to find the best score based on it's moves
    if isMaximizing:
        bestScore = -1000

        for key in board.keys():
            if (board[key] == ' '):
                board[key] = bot
                score = miniMax(board, 0, False)
                board[key] = ' '
                if (score > bestScore):
                    bestScore = score

        return bestScore

    else:
        bestScore = 800
        for key in board.keys():
            if (board[key] == ' '):
                board[key] = bot
                score = miniMax(board, 0, False)
                board[key] = ' '
                if (score < bestScore):
                    bestScore = score

        return bestScore


while not checkForWin():
    botMove()
    playerMove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not many things have to been changed when switching to an alpha-beta algorithm.

The algorithm adds two parameters, alpha and beta, and some lines to deal with those variables.

You can straight-forwardly update [the wikipedia pseudo-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode) to your code.

There are some bugs to your code :

1. You wanna call `miniMax` with a depth less each time. Therefore write
   `miniMax(board, depth-1, False)` (and not 0 as a depth). Also, in `botMove()`, call your `miniMax` with some depth (not 0).
2. Also, you wanna call `miniMax` with the other player. So `miniMax(board, depth-1, False)` if the current player is maximizing, and `miniMax(board, depth-1, True)` if the current player is minimizing.